# How can I accurately immitate this Picasa filter with Premiere's color correction filters?

Tags: video, premiere, filter, cs5, color-correction

I'm trying to color-correct a video I'm working on. This is an example frame from the footage:

[image: Original footage]

Since I'm a newbie and pretty clueless about good-looking color correction, I've tried playing around with some Picasa filters. Eventually I've came out with this:

[image: Picasa color correction]

This supposed to be a reference for me to later on immitate with Premire's color correction tools.

In Premiere, I've tried using Levels:

[image: Levels]

And RGB curves:

[image: RGB curves]

And this is the result:

[image: Premiere Attempt]

After a lot of small adjusments, still you can see a big difference:

[image: Picasa vs Premiere]

My main problem is that **whenever I'm fixing one color, or one area of the frame, always another part is affected in a non-wanted way**. For example you can see the wall in the Picasa version is more yellow than the one in the Premiere version, but the left-hand closet is less yellow than the one in the Premiere version. Meaning making the whole thing more yellow might fix the wall's shade but make the closet's shade worse.

**My question is, what method should I use while using these filters (or others) in order to achieve a known effect?** Is there a specific filter I should use before or after another? Or how could I determine the proper adjusment for affecting one color/shade but leaving another as it is?

This is important to me not only for this specific project, but also because I assume this **method** is what professional editors use when trying to achieve a specific vision they have for a frame.

Comment: Do you particularly like the the color grade you accomplished with picasa? Did that achieve something artistically and cinematographically that you were going for?

Comment: Which filter in Picasa did you apply, and with which parameters?

Answer (score 1):

This might be better suited as a comment to your original post, but alas I do not yet have those privilegies.

Anyway, my answer to you would be a cliché one: Keep tinkering.

It's really a matter of finding out what effects Premiere can offer, deciding which will be able to assist you the most and then going back and forth between them until you find a result that pleases you.

That said, you might want to check out the Color Balance effect. I find it very useful in most projects.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get better at coloring.. yes keep tinkering. If you want a push button possibility download try SpeedGrade and try some of the preset "Looks". Ultimately, for any auto correction to look exactly like the Picasa one would be a piece of chance.

I am by no means a color guru, but I found these resources helpful in some recent projects:

[Some quick basics](http://www.hurlbutvisuals.com/blog/2012/01/7-tips-for-hd-color-correction-and-dslr-color-correction/)

[Kind-of Concept Overview but interesting](http://provideocoalition.com/pvcexclusive/story/answering-the-essential-color-correction-question)

[Color Correction Tutorials](http://www.lynda.com/Video-training-tutorials/78-0.html?previousCategory=1298)